# Remove points from a UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, drawing, uibezierpath

I am using the `UIBezierPath` class to creating a drawing app. I am working on the eraser tool; however, there doesn't appear to be any method to remove points from the bezier path (only `removeAllPoints`). How should I go about erasing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store points to `NSMutableArray`, and if user wants to remove point, recreate whole path from array. There is no method to remove point from `UIBezierPath` or from `CGPath`.

Comment: how do you recreate the whole path?

Comment: I find redrawing the whole path could be not very effective.. is there an alternative to UIBezierPath where we can just remove points?

Comment: @juniperi but how it is possible please describe the code for to create UIBezierPath from Array please help...I am new in iOS

Comment: You can also store the bezier path objects instead of the points, then you'll have more freedom in terms of deleting specific path

Answer (score 2):

There is no method to remove points. I decided to draw a white bezier path where the user wants to erase, instead of removing points from the original bezier path.